# Trying to take objects out of an array, reverse them, and put them back in

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

as the title says I'm having an issue with taking objects out of an array, flipping them, and putting them back in. Below is the code I currently have that ends in this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectsAtIndexes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this? Here's a little more info on how I have it set up:

The object "PEG" is an NSString that displays  "-0.6", "4.36"

GlobalSortedArray is an array filled with dictionary containing the PEG object

```
//Declare variables
NSMutableArray *negArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableIndexSet *index = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init];
int negcount = 0;
NSDictionary *forLoopDict;


for (forLoopDict in globalSortedArray)
      {
          if ([[forLoopDict objectForKey:@"PEG"] hasPrefix:@"-"])
          {
              [index addIndex:negcount];
          }
          negcount++;
      }


NSLog(@"%@", negArray);

//    Removes objects from main array. This is what seems to be messing up.
[globalSortedArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:index];

//    Reverses the array
NSArray* reversedArray = [[negArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

//    insters them back into the main array
[globalSortedArray insertObjects:negArray atIndexes:0];
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that globalSortedArray is an NSMutableArray and not a standard NSArray and that it is instantiated already when you call the method?

Comment: `__NSArrayI` -> immutable array, `__NSArrayM ` -> Mutable array

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove an item from `globalSortedArray`. It is an NSArray and not mutable.

Answer (score 0):

globalSortedArray as NSmutableArray

NSArray -- > NSMutableArray